# typo3 extension development courious extension key

Tags: typo3

I am currently trying to develop my own Typo3 extension. It is in a very early stage!

composer.json says:

```
  "extra": {
    "typo3/cms": {
      "extension-key": "av_vcard"
    }
  }
```

The extension is installed in the directory: "av_vcard"!

In my controller I do:

```
$extensionKey = $this->getExtensionKey();
$this->view->assign('ext_key', $extensionKey);
```

getExtensionKey:

```
    public function getExtensionKey()
    {
        return $this->request->getControllerExtensionKey();
    }
```

In my flud template I have a debug statement:

```
<f:debug title="Templates/Show.html">{_all}</f:debug>
```

the output is:

```
array(2 items)
   settings => array(2 items)
      xxx => 'what so ever' (12 chars)
      flexform => array(1 item)
         vcardEntity => '1' (1 chars)
   ext_key => 'avv_card' (8 chars)
```

I would have expected to find in "ext_key" the "av_vcard" instead of "avv_card".

Can anyone tell me where this extension key comes from?

Comment: do you find "avv_card" when searching inside your extension? IMO there is no need to get the key from the request within your extension, why not just directly hardcode it?

Comment: I would guess that you have a typo for the extension key in the plugin registration (extbase).

Comment: @GeorgRinger: no! I have searched for with no results. Georg, I am a novice on this and trying some things to find around a bit. No productive use for it at all - anyhow.

Comment: @StefanBürk: 
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    // extension name, matching the PHP namespaces (but without the vendor)
    'AvvCard',
    // arbitrary, but unique plugin name (not visible in the BE)
    'vCard',
    // plugin title, as visible in the drop-down in the BE
    'LLL:EXT:av_vcard/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:plugin.avvcard',
    // the icon visible in the drop-down in the BE
    'EXT:av_vcard/Resources/Public/Icons/Extension.svg'
);

Comment: see AvvCard > this is transformed back to avv_card as key

Comment: @GeorgRinger: thanks. As novice I am a little bit confused on the various names. I have meanwhile learned about Extension-Key, vendor and Extension name. I was of the opinion after reading lots of documentation (T3 explained) that the Extension Name is not at all related to the Extension-Key. Seems to be a wrong conclusion. I will try to correct my setup. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment of @GeorgRinger it looks like the naming structure of the extension is set the wrong way.

Old was:

- vendor: Averlon
- Extension Name: AvvCard
- Extension Key: av_vcard
- Namespace: Averlon\AvvCard....

If I undertand it correct it needs to be:

- vendor: Averlon
- Extension Name: AvVcard (although this is not nice)
- Extension Key: av_vcard
- Namespace: Averlon\AvVcard...

Then they should fit to each other. I will give it a try!